# Roostagram node.js IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, gruntjs, npm

I've been successful in installing node.js and iisnode on my windows server running IIS.  I just got back from the jQuery/ROOST conference and I'm playing with the app that they put together.  For whatever reason after I've cloned the git repo and installed all packages with npm I'm still not able to get the app running.

I am able to run the app if I run grunt through the command prompt and it starts the test webserver on port 8000, however I would like IIS run the app and handle all requests...

Thanks!

p.s. here is the repo https://github.com/bocoup/roostagram.git

Comment: The sample server looks like its all node.js javascript you literally have to do this on your own from scratch. But as it looks its just a minimal server nothing fancy you should be able to make server-side on IIS or simply proxy requests to it.